# GDI+ is killing me with this "generic error"

Tags: .net, asp.net, image-processing, gdi+

Honestly, what is up with GDI+ running in ASP.Net? It works in so mysterious ways and the error descriptions are quite cryptic: **A generic error occurred in GDI+.**

Oh, thank you very much now I know exactly what went wrong... not.

Take a look at the code causing the error, and maybe you can help me?

```
var fileStream = fuImage.FileContent;
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();

imageStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
fileStream.Read(imageStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

imageStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();

using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream))
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
            bmp.Save(path);
        }
    }
}
```

This is actually a simplified version of my code, but it still causes the error. fuImage is a `FileUpload` control (.NET Web Forms).

**If you get this error, ensure the existence of the full path to where you are about to save the file... or you might get this "generic error" message.**

Comment: Do you have write permission in `path`?  What is the image format?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to save to that path before (from ASP.Net). It's a JPEG that causes the error.

Comment: What if you get your Graphics object from the Bitmap instead of from the Image?

Comment: @mbeckish that was actually a typo here at SO. Edited the code, but no it is still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the file into a `MemoryStream` and read that.
The Stream from a FileUpload is non-seekable, which GDI+ doesn't like.

Comment: Edited the code to copy the file into a MemoryStream, but I still get the same error. Is there another way to copy the file than the one I've used? (see edited code)

Comment: Yes I got it to work. The code above actually works fine, it was some code above this that removed the directory to where the image should be saved (this was a temporary directory before). So thanks!